# Java Heap space with CompletionService

Tags: multithreading, heap-memory

What could I do to fix this OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space:

```
17:29:23 ERROR pool-10-thread-2 storage.JCloudsStorageModule - Error on writing bucketIndex: 4167 and bucketOffset: 1044480
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule.getAndprefetchBuckets(JCloudsStorageModule.java:275)
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule.write(JCloudsStorageModule.java:318)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.stage.fullfeature.WriteStage.execute(WriteStage.java:223)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.phase.TargetFullFeaturePhase.execute(TargetFullFeaturePhase.java:197)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.Connection$TargetConnection.call(Connection.java:252)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.Connection$TargetConnection.call(Connection.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule$ReadTask.call(JCloudsStorageModule.java:401)
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule$ReadTask.call(JCloudsStorageModule.java:371)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    ... 4 more
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule.write(JCloudsStorageModule.java:328)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.stage.fullfeature.WriteStage.execute(WriteStage.java:223)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.phase.TargetFullFeaturePhase.execute(TargetFullFeaturePhase.java:197)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.Connection$TargetConnection.call(Connection.java:252)
    at org.jscsi.target.connection.Connection$TargetConnection.call(Connection.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule.getAndprefetchBuckets(JCloudsStorageModule.java:275)
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule.write(JCloudsStorageModule.java:318)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule$ReadTask.call(JCloudsStorageModule.java:401)
    at org.jscsi.target.storage.JCloudsStorageModule$ReadTask.call(JCloudsStorageModule.java:371)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    ... 4 more
```

My code uses CompletionService and ConcurrentHashMap. I am formatting a iscsi driver with jSCSI.org on linux with ext3. The strange is when I format with ext4 it goes well and the time is very fast. The line that throws the error is : byte[] returnval = startTask.get().getValue();

Thanks in advance, Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using wait() and notify():

https://sites.google.com/site/lipe82/Home/diaadia/executorservicewait

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space` error is thrown whenever the leaked memory fills all of the available memory in heap region and garbage collection is not able to clean it.

Try out to increase the availability of such a resource. When your application does not have enough Java heap space memory to run properly, fixing it is as easy as altering your JVM launch configuration and adding (or increasing if present) the following: `-Xmx1024m`

Or you can go ahead and try out [Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) for free. When we find the cause for the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` you will see the exact location of the problem along with solution guidelines.